# Roots for Matlab polyfit with mu for centering and scaling

Tags: matlab

I changed my code to used centering and scaling, as suggested in a frequently occurring warning message, using this form:

```
       [p,~, mu] = polyfit(tScan(observationRange),aScan(observationRange),npoly);
       tPoly = linspace (tScan(observationRange(1)),tScan(observationRange(end)), 100);
       aPoly = polyval(p,tPoly,[],mu);
```

But in the same code where I was previously finding to roots of the polynomial with this line

```
       threshold = roots([p(1:npoly) p(end)-thresholdLimit]);
```

It is no longer returning the same roots as before I used centering and scaling. The roots I was getting before were reasonable values.

The polynomial is 2nd degree, so it shouldn't be that complicated.

The Matlab roots function doesn't operate with the centering and scaling parameter.

What is really going on with centering and scaling, insofar as my polynomial coefficients are concerned? How does centering and scaling affect the calculation of the roots? I suspect that they have been centered and scaled, but I'm not sure how to transform them into useful values.

Comment: For the recentered & rescaled fitting ```[p,~,mu]=polyfit(x,y,n)````, the function computes first your recentered and rescaled x (using mean of x and std(x) given by the mu output). Then it computes the fitting polynomial coefficient. So the polynomial coefficients will be those of your recentered and rescaled x which is different from your original signal x !

Comment: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html  there are the details of the rescaling & recentering of x.
I'm not sure (it's a bit late to do maths for me) but try to compute your threshold like this :
threshold=roots([p(1:npoly) p(end)-thresholdLimit]) * mu(2) + mu(1) ; 
This should give you the right solutions if I'm right

Comment: Thanks, Kiwi. I did exactly that, and it seems to work. Feel free to write it as an answer, and I will upvote and accept it.

Comment: Okidoki I'm glad it worked and sorry for the lateness of this answer (last days have been crazy with city closing with covid) ! 
PS : By the way, if you're interested in quantifying the quality of the fitting with a number, tell me ! I'll dig in in some of my old matlab routines where I used to compute the correlation coefficient using the outputs the 2nd output of polyfit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the recentered & rescaled fitting `[p,~,mu]=polyfit(x,y,n)`, the function computes first your recentered and rescaled `x_bis = (x-mu(1))/mu(2)` (where `mu(1) = mean(x)` and `mu(2) = std(x)`). Then it computes the fitting polynomial coefficient. So the polynomial coefficients will be those of your recentered and rescaled `x_bis` which is different from your original signal `x`.

(On this link - https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html - there are the details of the rescaling & recentering of `x`).

So computing your roots using `threshold=roots([p(1:npoly) p(end)-thresholdLimit]) * mu(2) + mu(1)` should give you the right solutions if I'm right !